# How to get output from powershell script over ssh?

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh

For some reason, I can't seem to get output and redirection to work over ssh from linux to Windows. I have a powershell script that only outputs a message on each stream.

From the powershell terminal this looks like:

```
$ ssh me@windows.box.com
PS C:\Users\me> C:/"Program Files"/App3/bin/script.ps1 2> $null
This is output
This is to host
WARNING: This is a warning!
PS C:\Users\me> C:/"Program Files"/App3/bin/script.ps1 *>&1 2> $null
This is output
This is to host
WARNING: This is a warning!
C:\"Program Files"\App3\bin\script.ps1 : This is an error
At line:1 char:1
+ C:/"Program Files"/App3/bin/script.ps1 *>&1 2> $null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,script.ps1
```

But for some reason, from ssh commands, I can't get the other streams redirected to stdout:

```
$ ssh me@windows.box.com "C:/\\\"Program Files\\\"/App3/bin/script.ps1" 2>/dev/null
This is output
This is to host
WARNING: This is a warning!
$ ssh me@windows.box.com "C:/\\\"Program Files\\\"/App3/bin/script.ps1 *>&1" 2>/dev/null
This is output
This is to host
WARNING: This is a warning!
```

And to clarify that this seems to be a script specific issue:

```
$ ssh me@windows.box.com "Write-Host \\\"This is to host\\\""
This is to host
$ ssh me@windows.box.com "Write-Output \\\"This is output\\\""
This is output
$ ssh me@windows.box.com "Write-Warning \\\"This is a warning\!\\\""
WARNING: This is a warning\!
$ ssh me@windows.box.com "Write-Error \\\"This is an error\\\""
Write-Error "This is an error" : This is an error
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
```

Any ideas on how to get the script output redirected?

I did run into another issue with getting output when the script is run is different directories, but that's a battle for another day, another Stack Overflow post. I'm running RHEL, and the script content is:

```
Write-Output "This is output"
Write-Host "This is to host"
Write-Verbose "This message is definitely more verbose"
Write-Debug "This is marked debug"
Write-Warning "This is a warning!"
Write-Error "This is an error"
```

Comment: Is local machine on linux?

Comment: also, if script.ps1 is throwing some error, why don't see it on the terminal? Maybe publish content of that script for more clarity

Comment: @MikeTwc Hey Mike, thanks for your interest. I was trying to illustrate a point without actually doing any legwork, but it turns out one of my assumptions was wrong. I'm now more confused, but I've updated the question with all the stuff you pointed out.

Comment: forgot to mention *>file didn't work with ssh either, so that's why I used >file 2>file.

Comment: I just realized that it's location, partly. If I run the script from C:/test or my home directory, I get no output. If I run it from C:/Program Files/App3/bin/ I get output.

Comment: So you see the error output in the terminal after changing the folder? Does that folder has anything your script or powershell needs?

Comment: No, I'm still just using the basic script above with 6 Writes. It happens to be where the 3rd party script that I started with is housed, but that's because I noticed with that script. I moved the basic one in there to verify that it was the directory and not a script need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quickly recreate your environment (linux host / windows remote). I tried at least to imitate cross platform environment ( powershell on linux VM, ssh client on Windows). Here is some notes that might be helpful, at least if you are planning get those streams on the file

Unlike you, I got same output on my terminal when running this

```
ssh mike@Ubuntu "/snap/bin/pwsh ./test.ps1 *>&1"  (on local)
pwsh ./test.ps1 *>&1  (on remote)
```

Although I got  similar issue when trying to redirect output to the file over ssh (but it works if called from powershell session)

```
 ssh mike@Ubuntu "/snap/bin/pwsh ./test.ps1 *>&1 test.log" 
  #adds only original success to the file, and prints error on terminal
```

So it looks like stream to stream redirection is not working if invoked through the ssh. Although somehow stream to file seemed to work

```
 ssh mike@Ubuntu "/snap/bin/pwsh ./test.ps1 >test.log  2>>test.log" 
 ssh mike@Ubuntu "/snap/bin/pwsh ./test.ps1" &> test.log #redirection works again on local
```

So might be some weirdo bug of ssh/powershell interaction. You might try to use standard ps remoting protocol vs ssh (like Invoke-Command {echo 'hi'} -ComputerName YourMachine -Credentials $creds )

Comment: I have to use ssh for a number of reasons, not the least of which is that my local host is linux. I see that you invoke powershell (I assume that's what pwsh is) to run your script. Does that change any of the functionality?

Comment: yeah, pwsh is same thing as powershell.exe (just on linux). pwsh path or pwsh -c "command" should be the same thing as if you get into interactive ps shell and run script/file from there. Try to add redirection to file on your command see if file will capture error stream.

Comment: Redirection to a file works fine, including with a '*', which is different for your environment. This is all wonderfully finicky and idiosyncratic.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it points out an alternative to redirecting output, by redirecting it to a file. Unless someone knows what the issue is, I'm going with this.